# Determinar el tamaño, en bytes, de un arreglo asignado con malloc

Tags: c, winapi

Tengo un valor llamado `Value2`, de tipo `REG_SZ`, creado en la subclave:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\WinSide

Como método de aprendizaje, estoy utilizando la API de Windows para consultar el contenido de este valor, así que llamo a la función [RegOpenKeyEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx) para abrir la subclave y [RegGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868(v=vs.85).aspx) para obtener nombre y contenido de valor. Hasta aquí todo bien; el "problema" es que estoy utilizando `malloc` para asignar el espacio de memoria suficiente en el puntero `pData`(pvData en MSDN), que almacena el contenido de valor, así que necesito determinar el espacio, en bytes (pcbData en MSDN), de ese arreglo, pero al estar con `malloc` no tengo idea cómo lo consigo.

Este es el código:

```
int wmain()
{
    //RegOpenKeyEx
    HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    LPCWSTR pSubKey = L"WinSide";
    DWORD options = 0;
    REGSAM samDesired = KEY_QUERY_VALUE;
    HKEY hkOpenResult;

    LONG openKey = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, pSubKey, options,
                            samDesired, &hkOpenResult);

    if (openKey != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        wprintf(L"Error opening the key. Code: %li\n", openKey);
    else
    {
        //RegGetValue
        LPCWSTR pRegValueName = L"Value2";
        DWORD flagDataType = RRF_RT_ANY;
        DWORD typeOfData;

        //Asignación de memoria dinámica.
        PVOID pData = malloc(sizeof(WCHAR) * 255); 

        //¿Cómo obtengo esto sobre pData directamente?
        DWORD size = 255;


        wprintf(L"Key opened!\n");

        LONG getValue = RegGetValue(hkOpenResult, NULL, pRegValueName,
                                flagDataType, &typeOfData, pData, &size);

        if (getValue != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            wprintf(L"Error code: %li\n", getValue);
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"Value queried!\n");
            switch (typeOfData)
            {
            case REG_SZ:
                wprintf(L"Value's data: %s\n", (LPWSTR)pData);
                break;

            default:
                wprintf(L"Not set.\n");
                break;
            }

        }

        RegCloseKey(hkOpenResult);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Como ven, me está tocando crear una variable diferente, `size`, con el mismo tamaño que asigné al puntero, mas no es la idea.

¿Pueden ayudarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pides no es posible. De las FAQ de C:

[comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 7.27](http://c-faq.com/malloc/querysize.html) -

Traducción libre:

P. ¿Puedo interrogar al paquete `malloc` para encontrar el tamaño de un bloque de memoria reservado?

R. Desafortunadamente no hay una manera estándar o portable de hacerlo. (Algunos compiladores proveen extensiones no estándar.) Si necesitas saberlo, debes llevar un registro tu mismo. (Mira también la pregunta [7.28](http://c-faq.com/malloc/sizeof.html).)

Con información de [determine size of dynamically allocated memory in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Opté por utilizar RegQueryInfoKey para obtener el tamaño y usarlo por aparte del `malloc`.

Comment: Claro, no lo mencioné en la respuesta, pero es lo habitual, interrogar al sistema para saber cuántos bytes se necesitan, almacenar el valor en una variable, y luego hacer uso de este valor para reservar, llamar al API, etc.